# Data difference between web interface and database query in openerp

Tags: postgresql, caching, odoo

I have a working openerp 7.0 installation and everything seems fine. I can browse employees from web interface and the fields have values in it but when I login to database and query form there, those fields are empty!.
I guess some sort of cache is in between but, I don't know if openerp has any caching between postgres and itself or it is cache of postgres.

Thank you for you help.

Comment: They should be in the db unless it is a computed field, are you checking the right table?

Comment: I have only one database and it is not computed field. I guess it might be a result of bad restart of openerp or postgress.

Comment: If you saved the record from web interface it should be in the database, if you go to other menu and then back to employees? maybe its the wrong table.

Comment: My bad, all those fields are located in the resource table and I had moved them to resource and I forget to remove old fields from employee table.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Good then if you found the solution